# How to delete an element from list and all his duplicates?

Tags: haskell

I need to find max and min elements from list and remove them and their duplicate. I use

```
maximum(list)
minimum(list)
```

to find max and min but don't know how to remove all of them from a list.

Comment: Hint: use [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter will do what you need

```
removeMinAndMax xs = 
    filter (\x -> x /= listMin && x /= listMax) xs
    where listMin = minimum(xs)
          listMax = maximum(xs)
```